# Axios to Node (Express) GET Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

So using axios, I am attempting to make a request to my express server, here is my Axios request:

```
/* @flow */

import type {
  Dispatch,
  GetState,
  ThunkAction,
  Reducer,
} from '../../types';

export const USERS_INVALID = 'USERS_INVALID';
export const USERS_REQUESTING = 'USERS_REQUESTING';
export const USERS_FAILURE = 'USERS_FAILURE';
export const USERS_SUCCESS = 'USERS_SUCCESS';

export const API_URL = '/api/articleList';

// Export this for unit testing more easily
export const fetchUsers = (axios: any, URL: string = API_URL): ThunkAction =>
  (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: USERS_REQUESTING });

    return axios.get(URL)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: USERS_SUCCESS, data: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: USERS_FAILURE, err });
      });
  };

// Preventing dobule fetching data
/* istanbul ignore next */
const shouldFetchUsers = (state: Reducer): boolean => {
  // In development, we will allow action dispatching
  // or your reducer hot reloading won't updated on the view
  if (__DEV__) return true;

  const userListFetch = state.userListFetch;

  if (userListFetch.readyStatus === USERS_SUCCESS) return false; // Preventing double fetching data

  return true;
};

/* istanbul ignore next */
export const fetchUsersIfNeeded = (): ThunkAction =>
  (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState, axios: any) => {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    if (shouldFetchUsers(getState())) {
      /* istanbul ignore next */
      return dispatch(fetchUsers(axios));
    }

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    return null;
  };
```

and here is my code on the express server:

```
//GET ARTICLES
app.get('/api/articleList', (req, res) => { 
  console.log('hello');
});
```

It does not log "hello" and it displays no errors, I just think I'm missing something for the Axios to reach my server...

I had something similar working on another app but cannot seem to implement it here, I've searched online and cannot find a solution, any help or advice is appreciated - thank you in advance!

> **NOTE:** the Axios request works fine when the "API_URL" variable is
>   set to a myjson url link, so I know my action works fine, I just feel
>   like I'm missing something for it to reach my server

**EDIT:** Please see my entire server.js:

```
/* @flow */

import path from 'path';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import hpp from 'hpp';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString, renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import chalk from 'chalk';

import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';
import configureStore from './redux/store';
import Html from './utils/Html';
import App from './containers/App';
import routes from './routes';
import { port, host } from './config';

const app = express();

// Using helmet to secure Express with various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());
// Prevent HTTP parameter pollution.
app.use(hpp());
// Compress all requests
app.use(compression());

// Use morgan for http request debug (only show error)
app.use(morgan('dev', { skip: (req, res) => res.statusCode < 400 }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(process.cwd(), './build/public/favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), './build/public')));

// Run express as webpack dev server
if (__DEV__) {
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('../tools/webpack/webpack.client.babel');

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: 'minimal',
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
}

// Register server-side rendering middleware
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (__DEV__) webpackIsomorphicTools.refresh();

  const history = createHistory();
  const store = configureStore(history);
  const renderHtml = (store, htmlContent) => {  // eslint-disable-line no-shadow
    const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<Html store={store} htmlContent={htmlContent} />);

    return `<!doctype html>${html}`;
  };

  // If __DISABLE_SSR__ = true, disable server side rendering
  if (__DISABLE_SSR__) {
    res.send(renderHtml(store));
    return;
  }

  // Load data on server-side
  const loadBranchData = () => {
    const branch = matchRoutes(routes, req.url);

    const promises = branch.map(({ route, match }) => {
      // Dispatch the action(s) through the loadData method of "./routes.js"
      if (route.loadData) return route.loadData(store.dispatch, match.params);

      return Promise.resolve(null);
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
  };

  // Send response after all the action(s) are dispathed
  loadBranchData()
    .then(() => {
      // Setup React-Router server-side rendering
      const routerContext = {};
      const htmlContent = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routerContext}>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>,
      );

      // Check if the render result contains a redirect, if so we need to set
      // the specific status and redirect header and end the response
      if (routerContext.url) {
        res.status(301).setHeader('Location', routerContext.url);
        res.end();

        return;
      }

      // Checking is page is 404
      const status = routerContext.status === '404' ? 404 : 200;

      // Pass the route and initial state into html template
      res.status(status).send(renderHtml(store, htmlContent));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(404).send('Not Found :(');

      console.error(`==>   Rendering routes error: ${err}`);
    });
});



//----------------------------------------------------

//GET ARTICLES
app.get('/api/articleList', (req, res) => {

  console.log('yoyoyo');
    var indexLimit = parseInt(req.query.indexLimit, 10);
    var articleId = req.query.articleId
    var articles = [];

    db.collection('articles')
        .find()
        .sort("dateAdded", -1)
        .limit(indexLimit)
        .toArray()
        .then(result => {
            articles = articles.concat(result);
        }).then(() => {
            res.send(articles);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
});


//------------------------------------


//connect to mongo db
var db
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://##CHANGED###:test@ds123930.mlab.com:###/###', (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    db = database
    console.log('db connected');
})



if (port) {
  app.listen(port, host, (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(`==>   OMG!!! ${err}`);

    console.info(chalk.green(`==>   Listening at http://${host}:${port}`));
    // Open Chrome
    require('../tools/openBrowser').default(port);
  });
} else {
  console.error(chalk.red('==>   OMG!!! No PORT environment variable has been specified'));
}
```

Comment: What does `Chrome Developer Console`'s network tab shows ? Is there any network activity there?

Comment: So are you expecting to see the response in your browser console? You're express server is not responding to the browser because you're not sending a response. That request will hang open when that api endpoint is hit. If you're looking at your server console, and not seeing the hello log in your server console, then you're not using the right endpoint. The axios call looks fine.

Comment: I was expecting it to log the console.log('hello'); in my command line, but it doesn't seem to make it @KyleRichardson

Comment: how do I know what endpoint I should be using? @KyleRichardson

Comment: I would need to see more of your server and how your routes are setup to sure, but I'm guessing you might have something like `app.use('/api', routesApi);` somewhere and that you might need to drop the `/api` from the `/api/articleList` on that route, changing it to `app.get('/articleList', ( req, req) => ...`

Comment: hmmm, It uses app.use in a few places, please see the updated question to view the full server.js, thank you in advance! @KyleRichardson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to move your `/api` routes above:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    ...
}
```

Your call to `/api/articleList` is hitting that catch all route handler of '*' and responding to the request with the rendered page. When communicating with your api for data, you don't want a page render, you want the response from the api :)

Middleware is executed in order of appearance from top to bottom.